# How to extract "template" and "static" folder from resources directory

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using spring boot and thymeleaf. I want to extract template and static folder from resources directory.

And when application will deploy in server, I want deploy jar file and template separately.

I went to try write this configuration in application properties file.

spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/home/project/my_project/resources/templates
spring.resources.staticLocations=/home/project/my_project/resources

But I got this error

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$Thymeleaf2Configuration$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)

Comment: Try classpath:/home/project/my_project/resources/templates/, since the default value for this property is classpath:/templates/ (you are missing the last /)

Comment: Sorry same error:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$Thymeleaf2Configuration$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name